# Why autolayout constraints for a FOO view are set up on the main view, not on FOO view itself?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, constraints, ios-autolayout

I try to change autolayout constraints of a view (I name it FOO view here) programmatically, but I couldn't do it. I figure out the way to do it is enumerating all the constraints of the main view(I name it Main view here) of viewController.

My question is, why the constraints are attached with Main view, not with FOO view instead?

There
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if a constraint is having a relative constraint to its superview then its constraint will be in superview..,

while if the constraint is not relatively like fix width or height then they are in the view itself...

And reason behind that is apple designed it as so.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Er. Khatri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622328/2062785) is correct. It's a convention / definition by Apple and only their engineers can answer your question definitely. However, there is a very plausible explanation that I would like to add, supplementary to the rules that define to which view a constraint is added:

---

1. Constraints that only contain **layout attributes from a single view** are added directly to that view.

   - *Size constraints:*

     - `view1.width = 50`
     - `view1.height = 100`
   - *Aspect ratio constraints:*

     - `view1.width = view1.height`
     - `view1.width = 0.5 * view1.height`
2. Constraints that contain **a layout attribute from one view and another layout attribute from a superview** are added to the superview.

   - *Position constraints:*

     - `view1.leading = view2.trailing + 8`
     - `view1.bottom = view2.bottom - 8`
3. Constraints that contain **layout attributes from two different views non of which is the superview of the other** are added to their first common superview.

   - *Position constraints:* see above
   - *Baseline constraints:*

     - `label1.baseline = label2.baseline`

---

There are two reasons for that (that I can think of, maybe Apple has even more reasons):

1. **Plausibility:**

   Width, height and aspect ratio are *intrinsic* properties of a single view. They are not related to any other view. So it makes sense that this particular view *owns* these constraints. On the other hand, when you relate the positions of two views to each other these constraints are "shared" between the views. It's not clear which view should hold these constraints per se. So in order to avoid chaos we need a reliable rule which view to choose as the constraint's owner. The rules above unambiguous.
2. **Convenience for the layout engine:**

   Constraints are resolved from top to bottom (i.e. from superview to subview). As such, it's reasonable to always add a constraint to the view that's higher in the view hierarchy when "in doubt". That's also convenient for the layout engine because when it's laying out a particular view's subviews it already has these constraints at hand and doesn't need to ask its subviews for constraints (other than size and aspect ratio constraints).